# My windows xp wireless hotspot wifi isn't working

Tags: windows-xp, wireless-networking, hotspot

I add the hotspot [the regular way.](http://www.friendlybits.com/en/inf_tec_en/painless_wireless_en/convertingtohotspot_en/)

Yet it doesn't show up as available when I try to connect to it using my other Ubuntu laptop.
And nothing can connect to it. Yesterday, I successfully made it work for 5 minutes and then it stopped without me changing any configuration.

I've already tryed resetting the DNS.

Edit:
I've updated my Broadcom 802.11b/g driver to a generic but more recent version.

I've also [repaired the WMI](http://windowsxp.mvps.org/repairwmi.htm), now the advanced tab of my primary connection is available and the hand meaning the connection is shared appeared. But the computers still connect the wrong way around. (Windows to ubuntu instead of ubuntu to windows)

Reinstalled SP3...

Comment: Please [edit](http://superuser.com/posts/468477/edit) your question to include any error messages you are getting. Without them we can't possibly help.

Comment: How do I scan for error messages? I mean, what should I type in the cmd? Otherwise everything acts like it's okay. Ubuntu connects (but to nothing) and then my Windows laptop connects to Ubuntu (the wrong way around). I've just installed (http://www.connectify.me) which somehow works...

Comment: In windows XP there is [the event log](http://techtips.salon.com/log-windows-xp-error-messages-10691.html). But if you have found a solution to your problem please answer your own question, then after one day come back and and mark it as accepted. It helps other people with similar problems.

Comment: I don't consider installing a software (especially a shareware) that does what windows should be able to do by itself a proper solution.
I'll post what the log tells.

Comment: The log doesn't log anything. :(